# How can I concatenate a constant and a variable and store it in a class constant with PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, constants

```
class My_class
{
    const STATUS_ERROR = 0;
    const STATUS_OK = 1;
    const DB_TABLE = TABLE_PREFIX . 'class_table';
}
```

The two status consts work fine and can be accessed within class methods as `self::STATUS_ERROR` and `self::STATUS_OK` just fine.

The issue is one of how to stop the following error being thrown when I try to define the third constant.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/sub/sub/directory/script.php`

Comment: I also came across the same issue. Well, looks as a limitation for me. Mentioned also here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42355

Comment: The above bug was transformed into an RFC, and this was approved for inclusion in v 5.6 where this capability is now available: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't. Constants are constant. You can't store anything in them.

You can use a static property though.

```
class My_Class {
  public static $DB_TABLE;
}
My_Class::$DB_TABLE = TABLE_PREFIX . 'class_table';
```

You can't do it within the declaration, so you might prefer a static method instead.

```
class My_Class {
  public static function dbTable() {
    return TABLE_PREFIX . 'class_table';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

a const must be defined with a constant value, they can't be the result of an expression

http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php