# Assigning const value to const error in php

Tags: php, language-features, constants

```
<?php
 class Lala {
  const a = "a";
  const b = a . "b";
 }
?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' on line 4

What's the problem with it?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236018/how-can-i-concatenate-a-constant-and-a-variable-and-store-it-in-a-class-constant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 2):

mb

```
<?php
 class Lala {
  const A = "a";
  const B = self::A . "b";
 }
?>
```

Comment: This is NOT correct. a const cannot be the result of an expression.