# Concatenation in constant-definition

Tags: php, constants, concatenation

I'm trying to create a little enum and I'm just stuck: Why doesn't this work?

class.LayoutParts.php:

```
<?php
    class LayoutParts {
        const MAIN = 1;
        const FOOTER = 2;
    }
?>
```

class.SupportedLayouts.php:

```
<?php
    class SupportedLayouts {
        const MAIN        = LayoutParts::MAIN;
        const MAIN_FOOTER = LayoutParts::MAIN.LayoutParts::FOOTER;
    }
?>
```

It results the following message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /*****/class.SupportedLayouts.php on line 4
```

Thanks for your help!

Regards, Flo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236018/how-can-i-concatenate-a-constant-and-a-variable-and-store-it-in-a-class-constant

The answer seems to be in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is an operator, making `LayoutParts::MAIN.LayoutParts::FOOTER;` a statement, which isn't allowed in a `const` or property declaration.

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.