# Can't use string concatenation in constants?

Tags: php, constants

```
const
   SOME_PATH = __DIR__ . '/blabla.bla';
```

Doesn't work I get a parse error:

> expecting `','' or`';''

wtf!?

Comment: but I want it to be class constant:(

Comment: Not possible as this is not parsed in execution runtime

Comment: You didn't mention this was inside a class.

Comment: I think you're having the same problem as here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236018/how-can-i-concatenate-a-constant-and-a-variable-and-store-it-in-a-class-constant

Comment: @Matt Where else would you use `const` in PHP?

Comment: The problem is that you're doing concatenation in a class-variable definition. You can't do that.

Comment: @DanLee I wasn't thinking. I need coffee.

Comment: hmm it doesn't event work with static properties..

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I suck with "textbook" definitions of things, but my example should speak for itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the constant, it's that you're defining a class variable as a string using a non-literal.

```
const SOME_PATH = __DIR__;
```

Is fine, but once you start using concatenation, the parser throws a hissy fit.

It's the same reason why this works:

```
class myClass {
    public $something = "something";
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
class myClass {
    public $something = "some" . "thing";
}
```

Comment: @decereé you're right, but I *think* it's permitted. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Yeah, cause it's a *constant value*. That's the criterium.

Comment: @decereé excellent clarification. Like I said, I suck at "textbook" definitions. I'm better at conceptualizing than defining.

Answer (score 5):

You can only use *constant values* when declaring class constants or properties. No variable expressions.

Comment: OP isn't using a variable expression. OP is using concatenation of a constant and a literal. The problem is the *concatenation*.

Comment: Was trying to find the antonym of "constant value", which is apparently hard to get right. :)